# What conditions required for functions $f$ and $g$ for $\int^{cx} f(t) \, dt = \int^{x} h(t) \,dt $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus

suppose I have two functions $f$ and $g$ both mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

I wonder what conditions do I need to impose on $f$ and $g$ so that
$$\int^{cx}_{-\infty} f(t) \, dt = \int^{x}_{-\infty} h(t) \,dt, $$
for some constant $c$ and for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

One example this equation holds is that 
$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 2t &\text{if } t>0\\
0 &\text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. ~~g(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1/2t &\text{if } t>0\\
0 &\text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$
Then, choose $c=1/4$.

Likewise, my guess is that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ has to be linear(?) functions to hold my assertion. I wonder if my guess is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substitution $t \mapsto ct$, so first integral becomes $\int_{-\infty}^x c f(ct)\, dt$. 
Then, since the equality is true for every $x$, it must be $c f(cx) = h(x)$ a.e.